# Listing the local language in a resume

Tags: resume

Assuming I'm applying to a position in an English-speaking country, is it really relevant to list English within the languages section?

So far I had done so, but now thinking, it may be quite pointless as they are going to check the writing while reading the resume, and the speaking-listening during a phone interview.

Comment: Also assuming you are from a country where English is the dominant language and that everybody knows you have been born there and are no member of a minority that speaks a different language?

Comment: @CMW No of course, I think it was clear I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: In that case I think it is particularly imporant that you give some expectation of your level of english skills. Otherwise, how could a recruiter tell, if you actually speak the language, let alone at what level, without taking the time for an interview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any harm in putting a section that reads:

> Languages: English (fluent), French (fluent: spoken, somewhat fluent: written), Spanish (fluent), Klingon (fluent), ...

Even if the resume is *written* in one of the listed languages.

It probably will only be really important for situations where you may be expected to work with people who speak other languages, and I would hope that such expectations are obvious in any job posting you are applying to.

Answer (score 4):

I've generally assumed that if I'm reading a resume written in a language, that the applicant can speak that language.  That's not the same thing as "we are both local to the same area, therefore we speak the same language" - as that may be true in the US, but I'm not so sure it applies globally.

I'd go so far as to say if you are getting a resume translated into another language, it would be good to mention that this resume is a translation, because the reader would likely assume that the resume is your own work.

I've assumed in most cases, any "language" section would reflect languages other than the resume language.